# DOCKER - LAMP Stack issues - Premade Image

Tags: image, docker

Trying to setup a LAMP stack with docker,
and found and tried to used https://hub.docker.com/r/linode/lamp/

But I can't find and don't know how to access the files linked to the domain
or how to change the domain name from example.com and so on.

I think my real question is how do I change files or rebuild an image
from other people.

Comment: Use [`run -v`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/volume-shared-filesystems) to mount host directory inside docker container. Any change in the mounted directory from host, will be immediately applied inside container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to mention I'm not a big fan of this image + approach because it's bundling multiple microservices. I would recommend to use a container for apache2, a container for mysql etc.

But for the setup of LAMP. I'm using the [documentation](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/how-to-install-docker-and-deploy-a-lamp-stack/) provided on the site. 
I've a path `/xx/test/index.html` which contains some html. I will map the port of the container on my container port + mount my files to the right folder in the container.

```
docker run -p 80:80 -t -i -v /root/test/:/var/www/example.com/public_html/ linode/lamp /bin/bash
```

I'm using -ti and start a bash session. In this they are starting the apache2 + mysql service. (it is the approach of the official documentation. Not mine. It's a strange approach):

```
root@35d00285b625:/# service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                               *
root@35d00285b625:/# service mysql start
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                             [ OK ]
 * Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were
not closed cleanly.
```

After starting the services you can exit the container by pressing `ctrl + p` then `ctrl + q`. Now you can check your server-ip:80 to check your html code. If you want to replace example.conf you can mount your own apache2 configurations too.

If you want to change foldernames inside the image I would recommend to create your own dockerfile which starts with:

```
FROM docker pull linode/lamp
RUN changes..
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. It was part of the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Consider using `microservices` in separate containers. This will provide advantages like:

- Fault Containment
- Ease of Upgrades
- Eliminates long-term commitment to a single technology stack
- Easy to scale
- System resilience
- ...

Now Docker was created with having `microservices` in mind, so for your `LAMP Stack`, I recommend using `Apache+PHP` in a container and `mysql` in another container. To make your containers communicate to eachother, create a `userdefined` network and put both containers in it.

Now back to your question:

You have 3 options for using your custom configuration files:

1. You need to mount your configuration files when creating a container(Recommended):

   ```
   sudo docker run -d --name my-apache -v /path/to/custom/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf httpd
   ```

Please note this example is using `library` (official) `apache2` image from `docker hub`, You should consult image creator's instructions for custom images.

2. You can manually edit the configuration file inside a running container and `commit` it as a new image.

   ```
   sudo docker commit my-apache myrepository/myimagename:tag
   sudo docker run -d myrepository/myimagename:tag
   ```
3. Create your own image via Dockerfile, and using `FROM <base image>` directive.

Comment: Thank you. But isn't microservices a means to fix high activity big scale solutions instead of small scale projects? Would the overhead be worth it if only 100 people saw your website and so on?

Comment: Its a trade off, I will go for microservices if its even  for 100 visitors. because the resource overhead is pretty small. You will have less management overhead using microservices architecture. Imaging an upgrade scenario, You are using a custom lamp image, what if you want to update mysql and not apache, you need to create your own custom image, but using microservices + docker official images its a matter of `docker pull` command.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.